# Implementation of Triple DES outputs different results in both CryptoJS and gwt-crypto

Tags: angular, encryption, gwt, cryptojs

I am using [CryptoJS](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/) library for an Angular 2+ project, and I am using [gwt-crypto](https://code.google.com/archive/p/gwt-crypto/) library for a Java project. According to [this article](https://code.google.com/archive/p/gwt-crypto/wikis/Usage.wiki), it is possible to make an easy implementation of Triple DES, so I did it like this:

```
import com.googlecode.gwt.crypto.bouncycastle.DataLengthException;
import com.googlecode.gwt.crypto.bouncycastle.InvalidCipherTextException;
import com.googlecode.gwt.crypto.client.TripleDesCipher;
public class CryptoKit {
    private static final String LOCAL_KEY = "exampleofsecretkey4myapp";
    public static String encryptMessage(String textToEncrypt) {
        byte[] key = LOCAL_KEY.getBytes();
        TripleDesCipher cipher = new TripleDesCipher();
        cipher.setKey(key);
        String textEncrypted = "";
        try {
            textEncrypted = cipher.encrypt(String.valueOf(textToEncrypt));
        } catch (DataLengthException | IllegalStateException | InvalidCipherTextException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return textEncrypted;
    }
    public static String decryptMessage(String textToDecrypt) {
        byte[] key = LOCAL_KEY.getBytes();
        TripleDesCipher cipher = new TripleDesCipher();
        cipher.setKey(key);
        String textDecrypted = "";
        try {
            textDecrypted = cipher.decrypt(textToDecrypt);
        } catch (DataLengthException | IllegalStateException | InvalidCipherTextException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return textDecrypted;
    }
}
```

As I want to communicate with my Angular app, I tried to do the same exercise using CryptoJS, like:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class VdCryptoService {
  private static localKey: string = 'exampleofsecretkey4myapp';
  encryptMessage(message: string): string {
    return CryptoJS.TripleDES.encrypt(message, this.localKey).toString();
  }
  decryptMessage(message: string): string {
    return CryptoJS.TripleDES.decrypt(message, this.localKey).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
  }
}
```

But when I test my two apps, they output different encryption results. For example, if I test with "Example message" as input, I get:

`CryptoJS: U2FsdGVkX1/l7hDE9US+MQFcmBw3u2HWN45H3c8shsk=`

`gwt-crypto: ac5f6601d994bb6a9b7ea304a1523c99`

As an interest fact, both apps can encrypt and decrypt correctly, but they ouput different encryptions, and I do not know how to solve this, in order to communicate between them. Somebody could help me?, maybe I need procedures that I don't know about, or I'm doing the implementation wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: CryptoJS output looks like a _base64_ encoded string. And after decoding it is `Salted__D1\7a7G,` Decoded hex is `53616C7465645F5FE5EE10C4F544BE31015C981C37BB61D6378E47DDCF2C86C9`.  Maybe it will help somehow...

Comment: _gwt-crypto_ seems to be outdated, probably an up-to-date library would be more secure. In Java 3DES, CBC, PKCS7 and a 0-IV (the latter is generally insecure) is used. For a match, the same parameters must be applied in JavaScript and the key must be passed as a `WordArray`, i.e.: `CryptoJS.TripleDES.encrypt('Example message', CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('exampleofsecretkey4myapp'), {iv : CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('0000000000000000')}).ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);` see [here](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#ciphers).

Comment: Adam: yes, its true, thank you, I did not know that. Topaco: I also looked for newer libraries that I could import into my project, and the most stable one was gwt-crypto (version 2.3.0). I thank you very much, the suggestion you gave me has worked very well and I have better understood the implementation of the CryptoJS library.